# Setup and teardown temporary directory for a midje fact

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, midje

This is the skeleton of what I want to achieve

```
(let [temp-dir (create-temp-dir)]          ; setup
  (fact
    (do-something-with temp-dir) => true)  ; actual test
  (delete-dir temp-dir))                   ; teardown
```

The midje testing framework gives [access to lexical scope](https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/Setup,-Teardown,-and-State) (scroll down towards the end).  So this is what I'd expect to work:

```
(against-background
  (around :facts
    (let [temp-dir (create-temp-dir)]
      (do ?form (delete-dir temp-dir))))
  (fact (do-something-with temp-dir) => true))
```

But the compiler complains that it can't resolve the symbol `temp-dir`.  Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the square brackets around your wrappers. From the link you included:

> zero or more wrappers can be found in three different forms:
>
> (against-background [ wrappers ] ...)
>
> The wrappers apply to all the forms within the against-background.
>
> (fact ... (against-background wrappers ) ...)
>
> Semantically, this is the same as an against-background that wraps
>   this single fact. The against-background form can appear anywhere in a
>   fact's top-level forms, and there can be more than one. Note that it's
>   not surrounded by [].
>
> (background wrappers ...)